# Counting with Casework - Dices and Full Houses

Tags: probability

This problem is a real headache (though very interesting!) - Each of five, standard, six-sided dice is rolled once. Two of the dice come up the same, but the other three are all different from those two and different from each other. The pair is set aside, and the other three dice are re-rolled. The dice are said to show a "full house" if three of the dice show the same value and the other two show the same value (and potentially, but not necessarily, all five dice show the same value). What is the probability that after the second set of rolls, the dice show a full house?

So there are two main possibilities here: The three new dice rolled are the same, and along with the two dice set aside can make a full house. OR, one of the new dice rolled ends up the same as the two dice set aside, and the other two new dice show the same number. This can also make a full house. BUT, I have to also factor in the case that all of the dice could be the same, and I have to somehow subtract that from the total number.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: You outlined the steps correctly.  Given that you are starting from the pair $XX$ work out the probabilities of getting $XYY$ (unordered), $YYY$, $XXX$.  where  $X\neq Y$.  (if you like, you can combine the cases $YYY,XXX$ into the single case "all three match".).

Comment: Yes. I have thought about that. Would you mind making a full explanation for the XYY case? I'm having a lot of trouble with that one.

Comment: What are the probabilities (a) The three new dice rolled are the same as each other but not as the pair; (b) one of the new dice rolled ends up the same as the two dice set aside, and the other two new dice show the same number as each other but not the original pair? Then you have no subtraction issues

Comment: Ok.    There are $3$ places to put the $X$, $5$ choices for $Y$, so the answer is $3\times 5\times \frac 1{6^3}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!